# IBatis Saving and Retrieving Different Type of Data in One DB Column

Tags: java, mapping, ibatis

I have a requirement that I need to save different type of data (int, float, string) in one database table column. Presently, I have set the data type of column to BLOB.

Table in DB:

.........

OBJECT_VALUE BLOB

```
class ModelObjectValue() {

    public Object objectValue;

    //Getters and Setters of objectValue

    ...
}
```

Database column `OBJECT_VALUE` (Data Type Blob) is mapped to `objectValue` (Data Type java.lang.Object) property in `ModelObjectValue.java`.

Data in `OBJECT_VALUE` is either int, float or string. I successfully get the data in `objectValue` as `java.lang.Object`. But I can't convert/cast it back to int, float or string.

I have already tried casting object to Integer, Float or String class. But all did not worked.

Please guide me about this issue.

Comment: What do you want to actually store in the BLOB field? The Java serialization result? Which version of iBatis/MyBatis do you use? Show us your result map configuration, please.